# How to change unicode [0x0] character data from SOAP response

Tags: java, spring, soap

I am new to Spring WS and I have written a SOAP web service client to consume Soap based web service using Spring WS. I am  able to send request however I am getting error

> ERROR:  'An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

I just wanted to change this unicode character to empty string (i.e., "") before parsing response(pojo) object. Or How can I skip this Unicode character validation before parsing it response object.

Below is the log message

> ERROR:  'An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.'
>   Oct 13, 2015 5:46:57 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory createEnvelope
>   SEVERE: SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source
>   Oct 13, 2015 5:46:57 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
>   SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
>   org.springframework.ws.InvalidXmlException: Could not parse XML; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1532; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.
>       at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60)
>       at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:608)
>       at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
>       at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
>       at com.aig.dmp.service.impl.SoapGetWorkerInfoServiceImpl.getWorkerInfo(SoapGetWorkerInfoServiceImpl.java:92)
>       at com.aig.dmp.web.client.service.impl.GetWorkInfoServiceImpl.getWorkerInfo(GetWorkInfoServiceImpl.java:37)
>       at com.aig.dmp.web.client.controller.GetWorkerInfoFromWDSController.getWorkerInfo(GetWorkerInfoFromWDSController.java:50)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Blockquote

Comment: You should debug the program and see what the actual data is. This particular "character" may just be there because you are parsing something unexpected (like an image instead of an XML, or compressed XML) or corrupted. You should see what the actual data is and then decide what action to take.

Comment: When I checked response xml from SOAP UI then square boxes are appearing on that particular element's value. And this exception occurs just before parsing the response xml to Java object. I am using "org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" and jaxb2 for marshalling and unmarshalling.

Comment: If you see the whole XML and it looks fine except from that element, then that particular element is corrupted. Whoever is writing it is using the wrong encoding. It would be much preferred to correct this on the side that produces the XML than on the side that consumes it.

Comment: Thanks much @RealSkeptic, I discussed the issue with team who developed that web service to fix this problem. Now I am getting correct reponse xml from the web service.